# adding comments and from-to arrows in xskak looping

Tags: chess

I would like to add comments with from-to arrows in skak looping.
In the next code only the arrows are displayed, but not the comments

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{} %ups a bug, definition is missing
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}% castling
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%

\begin{center}
\[\newchessgame\]
\hidemoves{1.d4 \xskakcomment{ That's a good move! } 
 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 Bg7 4.e4 d6 5.Nge2 O-O 6.Ng3 c6 7.Be2 a6 8.a4 a5 9.h4 h5 10.Be3 Na6 11.f3 e5 12.d5 Nd7 13.Nf1 Ndc5 14.Nd2 Qb6 15.Qb1 Nb4 16.Nb3 Ncd3+ 17.Kd2 Qxe3+}
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[normalboard,%largeboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to, coloremph, color=red, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
  }% End of \xskakloop...
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is nowhere a `\xskakget{nag}` to retrieve and print the comment.

Comment: so how can the move notations be displayed in each board

Comment: Like in your other question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384424/adding-comments-in-xskak-looping), by adding e.g. `\xskakget{opennr}
\xskakget{lan}` where you want to see the move.